# Confusion on the duality between regular Borel measure and $C_c(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact space, $C_c(X)$ be the space of all continuous functions on $X$ with compact support, $M(X)$ be the space of regular borel measures on $X$. Then, if I understand correctly, the map $$\mu\mapsto \left(f\mapsto\int_X f\,d\mu\right)$$ from $M(X)$ to $C_c(X)^\star$ is an isometric isomorphism. Note that the corresponding functional $f\mapsto\int_X f\,d\mu$ may not be *positive* functional.

However, Cohn said in his *Measure Theory* that
[image]

Why here the functional is positive? Where did I have a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you allow your measures to be signed or not. A positive functional is a functional which assigns a non-negative value to every non-negative function; obviously non-negative measures will do this. But if you allow signed measures, you can get non-positive functionals.

Cohn's book likely takes the convention that measures are positive, i.e. give positive (really, non-negative) measure to every set, whereas in the Riesz representation theorem, you need to allow signed measures to get a surjection. It is similar to how if you force your measures to be real, you will only ever get functionals into $\mathbb{R},$ but if you want to look at *all* functionals into $\mathbb{C},$ you have to allow complex valued measures.

Comment: Many thanks! I see!!